# Could a humanoid spinal/neck structure support horns used for combat?

Tags: creature-design, xenobiology, anatomy, humanoid, combat

Bouncing off of this question from a while back: [What alterations without drastically altering their humanoid shape nor horns, can I make to my species that lower the risk of neck snapping?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/137777/what-alterations-without-drastically-altering-their-humanoid-shape-nor-horns-ca)

Let's assume that we have a roughly humanoid species with horns.  Without any radical alterations to the overall shape of the skull and spine, would it be possible for them to actually *use* said horns in combat without injuring themselves more than the target of the headbutt?

Comment: I would say no. There is like a single, albeit strong bone supporting our heads. Many animals with big horns have huge, muscular necks, which humans do not.

Comment: Whilst your question as-is is answered by the answer to the proposed duplicate, might I suggest if you wish your question opened again and ask for what specific design of horn would work for (concussive/pushing?) combat, that and swapping out one of your current tags for the [tag:science-based] tag should be enough to get it opened again and get you a more detailed answer - if that's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, if you give them a hand

A human spine cannot handle the stress of horned combat (there's a sentence I never thought I'd write). However, a humanoid creature has two arms that it often uses in combat. The attacker could hold the base of its horns and use its arms and shoulders to take some of the impact off of the spine. This is a tactic that would require a lot of practice to get right.

Comment: Would using you arms help out with the risk of concussions though?

Comment: I'm afraid this sounds like the idea that bracing your hands on the dashboard will protect you in a car crash.  I'd need to see some kind of evidence or at least reasonable comparison before I'd buy that premise. MAYBE if the horns were sharp and being used for stabbing/slashing. Even then, I think the skull is simply too fragile to tolerate the abuse.

Answer (score 1):

> Without any radical alterations to the overall shape of the skull and spine, would it be possible for them to actually use said horns in combat without injuring themselves more than the target of the headbutt?

No, animals like goats etc. that use horns for combat have an entire suite of adaptations to handle the stresses involved which range from everything to being fourlegged in the first place so that force is transmitted along a plane allowing their whole weight to be behind the horns to huge neck muscles and reinforced bones.

Just being bipedal is a disadvantage to this sort of combat.

Answer (score 0):

Combat style bull:
Ever seen a drunk person run into a wall head first?
Anyway a normal human won't die from horned combat. You can prepare for it by leaning against a wall headfirst to reinforce the bones and training the neck muscles.

Various problems:

1. Leaning forward is a sign of submission, in all cultures because it makes your neck vulnerable to attacks.  I can't see how you would align your attacks without doing so.
2. You can't see your opponent looking at the floor.
3. Sufficient long horns can be grabbed, which allows for easy grabbling moves to your opponent favour.
4. Horned fighters hitting anything will have concussions.
5. Your opponent won't be knocked over without at least twice the mass advantage even with a charge. Which opens your neck to retaliation attacks.

Combat style headbutting:
Properly more effective with horns, especially if you can poke out eyes. Allows for shorter horns, which are harder to grab.
Humans can headbutt each other...
Chinese martial artist train their foreheads to better perform in direct collision, they do this by meditation against a wall.
The only problem being their martial artist perform very poorly against mixed martial artist. To my knowledge no mixed martial art contains headbutting.

"Headbutts are largely considered as illegal in mixed martial arts, mostly because of the repercussions that it poses not only to opponents but to the very fighters initiating them." - mmawarfare.com